# how can i properly type the index signature on a nested for...in loop in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a `RootType` like this

```js
Type1 = {
 nestedProp1: string
 nestedProp2: string
}

Type2 = {
 nestedProp3: string
 nestedProp4: boolean
}

type RootType = {
  prop1?: Type1
  prop2?: Type2
}
```

And i'm trying to iterate through it to get all of the values like this:

```js
const root: RootType = {
  prop1: {
    nestedProp1: 'foo',
    nestedProp2: 'bar'
  },
  prop2: {
    nestedProp3: 'baz',
    nestedProp4: false
  }
}
for(const key in root) {
  for(const nestedKey in root[key as keyof RootType]) {
    console.log(root[key as keyof RootType][nestedKey]) <---- how do you get the index signature type for the nested type key?
  }
{
```

For the top level, `keyof RootType` works fine for the top level keys, but i can't seem to get the nested key type. I've tried `root[key as keyof RootType][nestedKey as keyof Type1 | keyof Type2]` which dosen't work, i've tried creating a new interface that extends the RootType interface with a nested index signature as a string, but typescript complains that `string` isn't compatible with `"prop1" | "prop2"`

I'd rather not modify the RootType as it is generated off of a graphql schema, and if i change it, it'll require a custom type definition in a config file that we'll have to maintain, so a local overload would be preferable, and the best possible solution would be a clean way of getting typescript to infer the key type in a for...in loop so it dosen't have to be casted at all.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. In your example, you're wanting to know how to get the values of the that nested object? Or the key names? Couldn't you just use vanilla js's [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as a last resort?

Comment: I'm trying to access the properties of the nested items. in vanilla js this is trivial, but in typescript, you must use a valid index signature if you have the `noImplicitAny: true` option set, which is a requirement for this project. I'm trying to understand how you can get the correct type for the nested index signature.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification. I think @Terry's answer below gets you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `const` to store the value of the current key-value pair at each level of the `for` loop, so that you can access the value in the `keyof typeof <...>` declaration:

```ts
for (const key in root) {
  const nestedObj = root[key as keyof typeof root];

  for (const nestedKey in nestedObj) {
    const nestedValue = nestedObj[nestedKey as keyof typeof nestedObj];

    console.log(nestedValue);
  }
}
```

[See proof-of-concept on TypeScript Playround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYoF4oG8BQUB2EDOwEAJgAoBOA9mAgFxQFkCW2A5lrgceVQEx0PM2AXwwZQkWPB4p07fIVKUwAZn7AmrOZ0VUALHQBGFCgBsIAQ2wYRY%20FABKx4HAmpMUKGCUIA-HReIWJ5KPH6SkDzWogDGFNgEUJQUwHSOyQEy7sFUtLIeHhwK3NR0AOQAZsalADRBBfJcIWUG5mSlQUK1Hl68dFn12sWqUKUtAF41dTgNOmD6UOXmJngQHVEYlWRQABSx8cBQANYQIFDMiU4AlHlQewmFxADyBgBWMknAANrHp%20Z4RycKOUoOIIECLskALoAblEHk2OzuBweRAA0iczthptpni9rv1bnF7jMAGpLACu0FQKNxnxR6N%20-x%204NB4JprxhcPyd1MEAAdCYKCxtiiySZKZdYR4REIgA).

Alternatively, if you prefer to stick to your older method of referencing the type of the object directly instead of the object itself, it is possible but that also means you need to use a union type for all the nested object keys:

```
for (const key in root) {
  const nestedObj = root[key as keyof RootType];

  for (const nestedKey in nestedObj) {
    // Can be very verbose, if your parent object has many nested object types
    const nestedValue = nestedObj[nestedKey as keyof (Type1 | Type2)];

    console.log(nestedValue);
  }
}
```

[See proof-of-concept on TypeScript Playround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYoF4oG8BQUB2EDOwEAJgAoBOA9mAgFxQFkCW2A5lrgceVQEx0PM2AXwwZQkWPB4p07fIVKUwAZn7AmrOZ0VUALHQBGFCgBsIAQ2wYRY%20FABKx4HAmpMUKGCUIA-HReIWJ5KPH6SkDzWogDGFNgEUJQUwHSOyQEy7sFUtLIeHhwK3NR0AOQAZsalADRBBfJcIWUG5mSlQUK1Hl68dFn12sWqUKUtAF41dTgNOmD6UOXmJngQHVEYlWRQABSx8cBQANYQIFDMiU4AlHlQewmFxADyBgBWMknAANrHp%20Z4RycKOUoOIIECLskALoAblEHk2OzuBweRAA0iczthptpni9rv1bnF7jMAGpLACu0FQKNxnxR6N%20-x%204NB4JprxhcPyd1MEAAdCYKCxtiiySZKZdYR4REIgA).

Comment: This does solve my errors and the code works, although the nested value gets a `never` type. However because this technically does work and silences the compiler i'll accept your answer.